# column name does not exsit

Tags: python-3.x, psql

my table name "Gzip_Master" it contains the column names called id, link and status now I want to update the status. I mentioned my code below.

I'm using python with psql. here my code shows error like update_value column name does not exist how to solve this error.

```
update_value = "Scraped"
query = 'UPDATE "Gzip_Master" SET "status"=update_value WHERE status IS null'
self.curs.execute(query)
```

Comment: You should use something like [Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) to enable the use of parameters to pass the data of the variable `update_value`.

Comment: if update_value is a string, then wrap it in quotation marks

Comment: @ArranDuff Look at the first line of the code...

Comment: @AndrewMorton, first line of the code just sets an unused variable. But the point I'm trying to make is that for SQL queries you need to wrap the string in quotes. For example in this case you would use something like 
`query = 'UPDATE "Gzip_Master" SET "status"=\'{}\' WHERE status IS null'.format(update_value)`

Sorry for the confusion. I should have been clearer :)
But this should definitely work. I have reproduced the error and tested the solution

Comment: thnks it's working

Comment: @ArranDuff It would be better not to suggest a method which can be used for SQL injection attacks and breaks if there is a quote in the value of the variable. It's a good habit to always use SQL parameters for safety and consistency.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Good points. I didn't know about SQL injection attacks. Just been reading about  them. Thanks for the pointers